# jquery resize only firing sometimes on window resize

Tags: jquery, percentage, window-resize

I have a div that I'd like the width to be 20 percent of the screen width, and then have the height also be what ever that value is.  I've set it up using jquery window width, but it seems to be really inconsistent.  It only changes the values sometimes, and only on window expansion, it doesn't do anything when you close the window.

you can see a demo of this here:  http://jsbin.com/otuvik/2/edit

thanks for any help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `document` and the `window` are not the same thing :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(window).on('resize', function() {
    $('#wrapper').css('width', $(window).width());
    $('#circle').css({
        height: $(window).width() * 0.2,
        width : $(window).width() * 0.2
    });
  }).trigger('resize');

});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/gjwSR/1/)

Comment: so why does $(window).resize(function() {
  $('#wrapper').css({
    width:$(document).width()
  });                      
  $('#circle').css({
    height:$(document).width() * .2
  });
}); not work compared to what you did?

Comment: The `document` is basically your `<html>` tag, which is only the same size as the `window` if you explicitly set it to the size of the `window`, which in either case you should just be using `window` instead, not `document`. Your code works for me, but doing like above should ensure that it always follows the window, and not something else.